# Is this SQL Server 2012 "exceeds single hemisphere" error actually an SRID error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, spatial

I'm trying to insert a polygon into a Geography type field in SQL Server 2012.

```
UPDATE tblProjects
SET tblProjects.Boundary = geography::STGeomFromText( 'POLYGON ((-93.30388806760311 27.994401411046173, -94.62224744260311 33.37641235124676, -79.70281384885311 31.80289258670676, -93.30388806760311 27.994401411046173))',4326)
WHERE tblProjects.ProjectID = 1;
```

I'm getting the following error despite the fact my polygon is in a single hemisphere:

```
Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geography": 
Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.GLArgumentException: 24205: The specified input does not represent a valid geography instance because it exceeds a single hemisphere. Each geography instance must fit inside a single hemisphere. A common reason for this error is that a polygon has the wrong ring orientation. To create a larger than hemisphere geography instance, upgrade the version of SQL Server and change the database compatibility level to at least 110.
Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.GLArgumentException: 
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.GLNativeMethods.GeodeticIsValid(GeoData& g, Double eccentricity, Boolean forceKatmai)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.IsValidExpensive(Boolean forceKatmai)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography..ctor(GeoData g, Int32 srid)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.GeographyFromText(OpenGisType type, SqlChars taggedText, Int32 srid)
```

[image]

I'm assuming this is an error associated with the Spatial Reference ID as the following returns `NULL`:

```
SELECT distinct Boundary.STSrid AS SRID
FROM dbo.tblProjects;
```

Am I correct in this assumption?  How do I go about setting the SRID?  My attempt returns an error:

```
UPDATE dbo.tblProjects
SET Boundary.STSrid = 4326;
```

Error:

```
Msg 5302, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Mutator 'STSrid' on 'Boundary' cannot be called on a null value.
```

Answer (score 2):

So it appears that the Ring Orientation is indeed the issue.  Apparently the output from my web mapper had the vertices in the opposite order that SQL Server wants them in.  I changed the order of the second and third vertices (this first and last are always identical to ensure the shape is a complete polygon) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646985/inserting-geography-the-specified-input-does-not-represent-a-valid-geography-in) and the `UPDATE` statement went through without any issue.

Now the fun part of figuring out how to solve this issue programmatically.